# Snapshot of a Xamarin.Forms.View

Tags: android, bitmap, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am making an application using Xamarin.Forms, and I need to make a snapshot of a view (including parts not currently visible). I know full well how to do this on android, but I haven't found any clues on how to do this with Xamarin.Forms.View
Is there a way to do this?

I can't write the code in android because the project with all the references to the views is a xamarin forms project, but if there is some xamarin trick to get the bitmap from a class in the .droid project that would be very helpful too!

I don't know if this is relevant but Im using custom renderers for android, if there is a way to comunicate the view with it's renderer it would be helpful to know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a Service. There are a couple ways to create a service. One way is to use a [DependencyService](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/). What may not be clear from that article is that you need to put the [assembly:Xamarin.Forms.Dependency...] attribute **before** the namespace in your class:

using xyz...
[assembly:Xamarin.Forms.Dependency...]
public class MyService:IMyInterface{...}

Then to get a reference to your native code use

DependencyService.Get()

An alternative is to use [Resolver](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/IOC) - essentially the same thing but registration doesn't depend on an attribute.

Then your service needs to find a reference to the native view to be able to render it to a bitmap. There are many options here: you can see how Forms does it but they may change it, or you can simply keep track of your own custom views and their renderers any which way it suit you (custom object property on your Forms class, global registry...). Once that's done you have a native service and the object you need to pass to it, it can return a stream or Image or just save to a file - also depends on your needs.